# Как сделать исключения?

Tags: jquery

Как исключить из поиска строку с классом 
 main-head-table
 ?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#search").keyup(function(){
           _this = this;
           $.each($("#mytable tbody tr"), function() {
               if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) === -1) {
                $(this).hide();
               } else {
                $(this).show();
               }                
           });
        });
    });
```

Comment: `$("#mytable tbody tr").not(".main-head-table")`

Comment: прекрасный пример о том, как написать длинный код на пустом месте

Comment: `$("#mytable tbody tr:not(.main-head-table)")` [с документации](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".as .a:not(.ad)").each(function(){console.log(this)});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="as">
  <div class="a ad">1</div>
  <div class="a af">2</div>
  <div class="a ag">3</div>
</div>
```